# Html: open the page in a new window. target="_blanck" - is that a typo?

Tags: html, window, target

I have found (with a letter **c**)

```
target="_blanck"
```

instead of expected

```
target="_blank"
```

in a project written by someone else.
It works and opens a link in a new window.
Is that a typo or am I missing something?

Comment: because it creates a new window with id "_blanck", since there is no window yet with that id. Try it twice and it will reuse the "_blanck" window, while _blank will ALWAYS create a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `target` attribute refers to where the contents of the link will be loaded in your browser. The browser will put the contents of the page inside the window/frame with that name, as long as it's not one of the special values `_blank`, `_self`, `_top` or `_parent`. See the [Frame target references](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.16) section in the w3 spec.

> Except for the reserved names listed below, frame target names
>   (%FrameTarget; in the DTD) must begin with an alphabetic character
>   (a-zA-Z). User agents should ignore all other target names.
>
> The following target names are reserved and have special meanings.
>
> **_blank** The user agent should load the designated document in a new, unnamed window.
>   **_self** The user agent should load the document in the same frame as the element that refers to this target.
>   **_parent** The user agent should load the document into the immediate FRAMESET parent of the current frame. This value is equivalent to _self if the current frame has no parent.
>   **_top** The user agent should load the document into the full, original window (thus canceling all other frames). This value is equivalent to _self if the current frame has no parent.

So, if the link is supposed to always open a new window, it should be `_blank`. If there are several links with the same `target=_blanck`, it might be like this on purpose if they're supposed to always replace the contents of the same window.

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qypzz/1/):

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">This opens SO always in a new window</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blanck">This opens google in a given window</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blanck">This opens SO in the same given window</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes its a typo

```
target="_blank"
```

Will open in a new window

```
target="_blanck"
```

Will open in a tab named blanck, if there is not a tab named blanck it will open a new one.

My guess is if you click that link it will open in a new window, click it again and it will reload the same tab it opened previously

Comment: It's not necessarily a typo. *Maybe* the author intended to open a new window called `_blanck`. (Not very likely, I agree.)

Comment: I find that highly unlikely :)

Comment: You are absolutely right. If i click that link the second time, it jumps to that opened already page. If I use blank (not blanck), it opens a new page. 
Can it be a good practice to use it for jumping to that page? I'm just asking if that's a typo and I have to fix it or somebody is too smart and use it for the purpose you've described above:)

Comment: You can be pretty confident thats a typo :p. If someone was too smart they wouldnt name it "_blanck" as that would be confusing as hell

Comment: I'd hardly assign the window an id such as `blanck` on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is:
`<a href="/" target="_blank">Home</a>`

Comment: Safari detected spelling errors, I typed `_blanco` once, as a mistake, and it ignored the spelling error and opened a new window

Comment: Actually read my answer above it is most likely the same thing the OP experienced

Comment: No need for a -1, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The main method to give hyperlink in HTML is,

```
<a href="url" target="_blank">CLick Here ...</a>
```

where  is HTML tag and href and target is attribute. If you write target="_blanck" its means that you have an HTML page named _blanck and its gives you error.